# How can I display the percentage and value in a SSRS pie chart legend?

Tags: reporting-services, report, legend

In an SSRS pie chart legend, I'm easily able to show the value of the fields by right clicking the chart > properties > legend properties > clicking the function icon and entering the this expression: `=(Fields!myField.Value)` I can also easily show the percentage of each field using `#PERCENT` however I'm unable to find the correct syntax for concatenating the two. I have tried the most obvious:
`=(Fields!myField.Value) & " " & Cstr(#PERCENT)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
=(Fields!myField.Value) & " " & ((Fields!myField.Value)/SUM(Fields!myField.Value, "myDataSetName"))
```

Here's an example...

I created a simple dataset and pie chart. Then I Right-Click on any of the pie segments then select `series properties`. Next click the `Legend' tab and set the`Custom Legend Expression` something like the above. In my case I used the following...

```
=(Fields!Amount.Value) 
& " (" 
& Format(((Fields!Amount.Value)/SUM(Fields!Amount.Value, "DataSet1")), "p2")
& ")"
```

The design looks like this.

[image]

And the finished chart looks like this

[image]

Comment: This answer is definitely on the right path as using this I no longer get an error but it still shows the value not the Value and the percentage. Strange part is if I omit everything to the right of the second & symbol. it still only shows the value. no percent.

Comment: I'll updated my answer. I'm not sure you are setting the correct property

Comment: I found `#AXISLABEL (#PERCENT)` Outputs the result I'm looking for. I will assume there is a data issue on my end and accept the answer. thanks for providing a detailed solution.